# How to get the values of term store using JSOM?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, 2016, managed-metadata, term-store

Can anyone help on this.

I am getting the below error.

> The collection has not been initialized. It has not been requested or
>   the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly
>   requested.

following is the code.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

    var scriptbase = _spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl + "_layouts/15/";

    $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js", function(){
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", function(){
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Taxonomy.js");
            // SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded('SP.taxonomy.js');
            ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(execOperation, "sp.taxonomy.js");
        });
    });
});


function execOperation(){

    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();    
    console.log(context);
    //Current Taxonomy Session
    var taxSession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(context);
    //Term Stores
    var termStores = taxSession.get_termStores();
    //Name of the Term Store from which to get the Terms.
    var termStore = termStores.getByName("Managed Metadata Service");
    //GUID of Term Set from which to get the Terms.
    var termSet = termStore.getTermSet("8a675225-852f-48ed-af73-8fd8e5ccdc14");
    var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();
    context.load(terms);
    termEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator();

    context.executeQueryAsync(function(){
        var termEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator();
        var termList = "Terms: \n";
        while(termEnumerator.moveNext()){
            var currentTerm = termEnumerator.get_current();
            termList += currentTerm.get_name() + "\n";
        } 

        alert(termList);

    }, function(sender,args){

        console.log(args.get_message());
    });
}
```

Comment: please use a debugger and see where the error occurs (which line?) and update your question.

Answer (score 1):

Comment the line

```
termEnumerator = terms.getEnumerator();
```

before you are calling the `context.executeQueryAsync()` getEnumerator will not be initialized before the executeQueryAsync function